# login but only using DOM and XML

Tags: php, xml, dom

Im having this problem

**Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context**

Here's my code

```
$parentuser = $xml->getElementsByTagName('users')->item(0);
    $childuser = $parentuser->getElementsByTagName('username');
    $childpass = $parentuser->getElementsByTagName('password');

    for ($i=0; $i<$childuser->length; $i++)
    {
        $curruser->item(i) = $childuser->item(i)->firstChild->data;
    }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure that that's JS?

Comment: Guess I titled it wrong. Its in my .php file. Im using <form> in my html.

Comment: You cannot assign a value to `$curruser->item(i)`. Ah, as Enak says below.

Comment: oh... ok Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `$curruser` is but this line seems to be wrong:

```
$curruser->item(i) = $childuser->item(i)->firstChild->data;
```

You probably get some form of item as return and try to assign a value to it.

Comment: $curruser is an array I declared